# How to specify proportions using wxPython's BoxSizer

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to create a layout where one wxPanel takes up 2/3s of the window and one takes 1/3 of the window. I know how to make them 50/50 or how to specify minimum and maximum sizes. But is there a way to specify what proportion of the available space to take up?

```
import wx

eng = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='wxPython')

main_panel = wx.Panel(frame)
main_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,0,0))
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

left_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
left_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,255,0))
main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

right_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
right_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,255))
main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

frame.Show()
frame.CenterOnScreen()

eng.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proportion` parameter to the `sizer` will control this for you.

Change the `proportion` value to one of the sizers entries to 2, it will make the `sizer` allot twice as much space to that entry.

> The proportion defines how large the sizer’s children are in relation to each other. In a vertical sizer, this changes the height; in a horizontal sizer, this changes the width.

[image]

Here, the righthand panel has been amended.

```
import wx

eng = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='wxPython')

main_panel = wx.Panel(frame)
main_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,0,0))
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

left_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
left_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,255,0))
main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

right_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
right_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,255))
main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 2, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

frame.Show()
frame.CenterOnScreen()

eng.MainLoop()
```